# Android libc version and malloc implementation

Tags: android, malloc, libc, bionic

What libc implementation is used in Android platform? What malloc implementation is used (ptmalloc or tcmalloc or anything other)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

libc is [Bionic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bionic_%28software%29) and malloc is  [Doug Lea version](http://g.oswego.edu/dl/html/malloc.html) named [dlmalloc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation#dlmalloc) (with USE_LOCKS enabled for thread-safety).

Update: dlmalloc was removed in january 2016: https://github.com/android/platform_bionic/commit/c650447239352d43acc2fd99a8579a85ae0469ab https://sourceforge.net/p/android-x86/bionic/ci/0ac0cee0d1ab60a92103a5021e76ec31da2e3234/ "Merge "Remove dlmalloc.""

```
+libc_malloc_src := bionic/jemalloc_wrapper.cpp
+libc_common_c_includes += external/jemalloc/include
```

So, Android 7 uses external malloc implementation jemalloc (from FreeBSD/Facebook) - http://jemalloc.net/ and https://github.com/jemalloc/jemalloc; android variant of code is there: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/jemalloc/

Comment: For reference, here's the source code for the dlmalloc used by Android (git master): https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic.git/+/master/libc/upstream-dlmalloc/

Comment: Other link for source code: http://code.metager.de/source/xref/android/4.4/bionic/libc/upstream-dlmalloc/ (5 This code is imported from: ftp://g.oswego.edu/pub/misc/
6 It is currently version 2.8.6.). Still here at android 6: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/android-6.0.1_r55/libc/upstream-dlmalloc/ but not in android 7: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/android-7.0.0_r27/libc/